# How to connect to a VPN with L2TP/IPSec without shared secret, as if in windows?

Tags: macos, vpn

For example, I can connect to a L2TP/IPSec VPN without entering any shared secret in windows as the following settings:

[image]

and the required DNS:

[image]

Now I want to connect the same VPN in Mac, so I new a VPN as if in windows:

[image]

also enter the required DNS:

[image]

However, what is the equivalent option of "no need to enter shared secret" in macOS? Seems it force me to enter a shared secret:

[image]

What I tried: select "Self-signed root certificate" as a cert (which I don't know what the cert is, just think it is a dummy thing as "Use certificate for autontication" in windows):

[image]

but I still unable to connect to the vpn as windows, when trying to connect, the following dialog shows (in text):

```
The L2TP-VPN server did not respond. Try reconnecting. If the problem continues, verify your settings and contact your Administrator.
```

So what is the reason? Does Mac failed to support the same connection function ("no shared secret" option) as if in windows? Or it is the VPN server problem (eg: VPN server sets it accepts windows connection only)?